# How do I to calculate note's frequency using no intervals?

Tags: intervals, frequency

To calculate frequency of a note you should [know the amount of semitones between the note and A4](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/NoteFreqCalcs.html).

> 2<sup>x/12</sup> * f<sub>fixed</sub> = f<sub>given</sub>

where:
*x* – is the quantifier, based on amount of semitones between given note and fixed one (`A4`);
*f<sub>fixed</sub>* – is the frequency of fixed note (~A4 = 440 Hz);

For example, since `C4` is *nine* semitones *lower* than `A4`, the quantifier for it will be `-9`.

---

So, whether it is possible to calculate its frequency **without** knowing of this interval? Is there any other frequency-of-a-pitch equation that doesn't use intervals in it?

Comment: I have no idea, how you want to specify the tone for which you want the frequency if not counting to some reference. You could use a MIDI mapping from note number to frequency but even MIDI counts semitones.

Comment: @guidot: Maybe, you understood me wrong. It definitely must be regular note, such as C4, or G2 doubly flat, or another. But within my initial conditions (which are out of stage here) I will not be able to define the interval.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Is this an XY problem? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: There are no inherent mathematical properties in the letters A-G that can enable them to be translated to frequencies without the use of a constant. The letter assignments are completely arbitrary; thus you need some kind of constant to define them — 440 Hz. Your equation makes use of the number 12, so you clearly have the ability to define a constant value in your equation; if all you're trying to do is create a function definition f(p) where p is the pitch, the frequency of which is being calculated, then this is really an algebra question.

Comment: @NReilingh: All I want is to get 261.6255… for `C4` without using `amount of semitones` variable. And it doesn't seem to be algebra-question.

Comment: f(given) = 2^((given-A4)/12) * 440

Comment: @NReilingh: Yep. As I said, it's __not__ that is needed.

Comment: @Dave: I'm sure, it is not XY-problem :)

Comment: My function doesn't have a 'number of semitones' argument. It just takes a given pitch. You MUST, as part of the formula/function, find the difference of that pitch from A4 in order to complete the calculation.

Comment: I do think this is an XY problem, frankly. What are you trying to accomplish by answering this question? Are you just having trouble translating note names into numeric values?

Comment: Listen Dmitry, you have two options. One is map the pitches and avoid any kind of calculations. Two is calculate each based on some kind of reference pitch in semitones. There is no third options as how a pitch is defined in the system is by referencing other pitches in the system you are using. These's got to be some correlation between the input you give and the pitch of the output in a given system.

Comment: @NReilingh: No, no. I'm a JavaScript programmer. There are `Objects` there (kinda computeral beings). In my case, each `Object` has a property named `frequency`. Now Iam creating algorithm, that will calculate frequency of for given note. Unfortunately, I can't use intervals, due to the very initial conditions of my issue, — it is defined directly. So I must resolve it, or say, that it is unsolvable

Comment: I can write you a JavaScript function that takes an absolute pitch and outputs a frequency. It should be obvious how to do this from the information already here. But any reasonable solution would make use of subtraction arithmetic from constant values. It is unclear what your constraint is--is this some kind of programming riddle?

Comment: The answer to your question as written is "No, it's not possible." This is because a pitch->frequency conversion actually requires a second argument that defines the tuning system in use. When you omit this, we assume that the tuning system will be 12-tone equal temperament at A=440Hz, and so this information must be embedded in your formula as constants.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky the content of your comment to NReiling (about Objects and whatnot) indicates to me that you are trying to solve a problem that is not laid out in the body of this question --  what are the constraints that prevent you from just doing the math laid out in this question?  They should be in there.

Comment: Agreed with Dave. Ultimately, without a rationale for the constraints this question appears to be nonsense.

Comment: The question is answered now. I don't really understand  why downvote it, but, anyway, — valid answer has been given: "Not possible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either needed a reference pitch to calculate all other notes or you need to have all the pitches defined. Every  formula to obtain a pitch needs a reference pitch and you need to know how that pitch relates  to the one you are calculating.

The pitch you are using is relative to a system whether it is equal temperament, just, Pythagoras, ect. The pitches you build off each  Not even every A4 is 440 Hz. There are a lot of different  groups that use other frequencies like 435 or 441.

As long as you have a way to figure out which of the 12 notes you are dealing with (if you are using equal temperament like you seem to be) the rest is easy. You must have some method to know the difference between an A, A#, B, C, ect.

After you figure out the 12 base reference pitches of each note the calculations are simple as you only need to calculate one octave then double the frequencies to get an octave up and half to get an octave down which is valid regardless of system. For example, A3 which is an octave below A4 would map to the pitch 220 Hz and A5 which is an octave above A4 would map to 880 Hz.